# rails doesn't want to load json-schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I develop a rails project and I would like to use the `json-schema` gem. So I added it to the `Gemfile` via `bundle add json-schema`. However, when I want to use this via by running `rails console`

I have this classic error

```
rails console
Running via Spring preloader in process 27970
Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.1)
2.5.1 :001 > require "json-schema"
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from (irb):1
LoadError (cannot load such file -- json-schema)
```

**I'm pretty sure the gem is correctly installed:**

- there is a line in the `Gemfile` of my rails project
- I use rvm to setup my ruby environnment and I have currently only one
  version installed.
- It's not the first gem I use for my project, all the others one work fine.

```bash
bundle info json-schema
* json-schema (2.8.0)
Summary: Ruby JSON Schema Validator
Homepage: http://github.com/ruby-json-schema/json-schema/tree/master
Path: /home/mcdostone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/json-schema-2.8.0
```

I tried to load the gem with `irb` and it **worked perfectly**.

Any idea what's going wrong with rails?

Comment: mistake when copy/paste

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you done `spring stop` in the console?

Comment: nope, this is a raw copy/paste from my terminal !

Comment: I noticed `Running via Spring`. May be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you **jvillian**, It works now

What I did:

```
 $ spring stop
 $ rails c
 Running via Spring preloader in process 31305
 Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.1)
 2.5.1 :001 > require "json-schema"
  => true
```